# C algorithm for Hopcroft-Karp

Tags: c, graph, matching

I am working on graph algorithm theories (I am mathematician nothing with computer science yet) and I do have some matching problems to self, for which I am using Hopcroft-Karp for serious reasons ([Hopcroft–Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm)).
I don't want to solve them by hand with it, so I would like to use a program for it. But because I am learning C, I would be interested in having a C code to solve it. I found a couple of ideas for C++, but I am not able to read this yet (might be the next programming language in some years...)

Does anybody of you has a good C programmed Hopcroft Karp algorithm on his computer who wants to share it with me and the community? It's not just the code, I would be amazed of having an explanation of how it's working in C. I cannot image how to use BFS and DFS using pointers yet.
Thanks in advance if anybody has a code code+explanation.

====

Edit:
As I said to Young Developers, I have now forked the repo and tried to implement it to C as far as I was able to without much knowledge of it.
You can find everything inside the main.c file, there is no header or so existing. Every place where a "TODO" is situated means, there is something left to do.
So in the moment, I implemented and changed everything to C functionality, as you can see here.
https://github.com/Dabendorf/hopcroft-karp/blob/master/main.c

It's compiling, but there is one mistake somewhere which I cannot find, because it gives wrong results.
It have something to do with the fact, that the original author counts from one and I am using a normal array, counting from zero. But thats just speculation of mine.
So the mistake can be somewhere else as well.

Does anyone see it?

Comment: Have you seen this implementation https://github.com/vermagav/hopcroft-karp in C++?

Comment: Thats quite interesting, although I've seen it before. I am not 100% sure about the input of input_data function. Imagine I do have 8 nodes (2x4) and they all have 10 edges in total, then both sides have indize of 1 to 4 and I need to enter pairs of numbers, telling where the edges are bordering?

Answer (score 1):

Vermagav implementation [Hopcroft–Karp Algorithm](https://github.com/vermagav/hopcroft-karp/blob/master/algorithm.cpp) is with class and other features don't directly map to C. Maybe it is your best option start with that implementation. If start create Github fork of Vermagav project we all can help you.

Comment: Why dislike my comment. Without comment?

Comment: That's an interesting idea. I might fork this today and have a look for implementation in C.

Comment: Thanks Melmac271! Let us know when have done it. Maybe we can help. Buts ave C++ implementation in same project, so it possible compare the performance between implementation in two languages.

Comment: Well in fact, I just need one program in any language to calculate my graph problems, so C++ would be fine, but now the ambition came to me to implement it myself in a language I am learning (C)... So we will see

Comment: Hey @Young Developers, I have edited my first post with some comments and link to the repo.